# Pi Pico Won't Connect to WLAN When Plugged into Wall. Works plugged into computer

Tags: wifi, microcontroller, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a Raspberry Pi Pico W with the presoldered headers.

When I run the following code (main.py) through Thonny on my PC I am able to connect to the internet no problem. When I try to run it after plugging it into the wall, the LED just keeps blinking twice (meaning `wlan.status() == 0`.

```
import network
from time import time, sleep
import secrets



def light_onboard_led():
    led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)
    led.on();
    
# Define blinking function for onboard LED to indicate error codes    
def blink_onboard_led(num_blinks):
    led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)
    for i in range(num_blinks):
        led.on()
        sleep(.2)
        led.off()
        sleep(.2)

def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(secrets.SSID, secrets.PASSWORD)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        wlan.connect(secrets.SSID, secrets.PASSWORD)
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        blink_onboard_led(2)
        sleep(1)
    blink_onboard_led(wlan.status()+2)
    print(wlan.status())
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'Connected on {ip}')
    return ip


try:
    ip = connect()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    machine.reset()
```

I am expecting the onboard LED to blink 2x for a few iterations (when wlan.isconnected() evaluates to False) then connect to the internet. It would indicate this by blinking 5x.

Comment: You could enhance the blinking code inside the `while` to show `wlan.status()`, too. This way you might know _why_ the Pico does not connect. -- What happens to the characters `print`ed? Will it be a problem if there is no receiver?

Comment: Raspberry Pi Foundation's own software examples do not keep repeatedly calling `wlan.connect()` while waiting for connection... https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/get-started-pico-w/2

Comment: Are you sure that you are using a power supply that can supply enough current to the Pico, and a good cable?